# Human readable URL in azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, azure

I have an azure cloud service with a couple worker roles, a WCF web role and a normal web role containing a couple aspx pages. Both roles are set to use https endpoints.

When testing locally in Visual studio using IIS the default.aspx page and the servicename.svc page both open in the browser. When I publish to azure though, the URL with the random string of characters opens the directory containing the service definition, but I can’t access the default.aspx page from that URL.

For example if my URL is randomstring.cloudapp.net after publishing, randomstring.cloudapp.net/wcfservice.svc works, but randomstring.cloudapp.net/default.aspx does not. I can get to the other page by using the IP address given in azure, but this isn’t really what I need. Furthermore, the cloud service URL does not work at all. mycloudservice.cloudapp.net results in webpage not found.

Do I need to do something special in order to get both the service, and the aspx pages to show up under mycloudservice.cloudapp.net? I can post the config files if need be, but as of right now, I don't think there relevant to the problem.

**EDIT:**

Just to clarify, I have now published to production, and the service is working  [mycloudservice].cloudapp.net/[mywcfservice] and I can get to the website without a 404 error if I enter the port like [mycloudservice].cloudapp.net:8081/default.aspx . Is there a way to make everything show up under [mycloudservice].cloudapp.net/ without entering the port number so I can just type in [mycloudservice].cloudapp.net/[mywcfservice] AND [mycloudservice].cloudapp.net/default.aspx into the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I guess you published your project to the stage slot of your cloud service. It's [Deployment ID].cloudapp.net. You will use the URL you specified if you deploy it to production slot.

Ref the problem, that '[randomstring].cloudapp.net/default.aspx' doesn't work, I'm not sure what you mean by 'doesn't work'. Is it 404 erroe? Or some asp.net runtime error. More information might be helpful.

Comment: You were right about publishing to production. Cant believe it was that simple. I have edited my original post.

Comment: I'm not sure why you specified port 8081 when you view your default.aspx. If the wcf web service and web pages are in the same project, you should be able to view then on the same port you bind (default is 80). What happened if you go [mycloudservice].cloudapp.net/default.aspx?

Comment: If I try to browse to it without the port I get a 404 "The resource cannot be found" error. What do you mean by "you should be able to view then on the same port you bind"? Each role has different endpoints with different public ports which I configured by right clicking on the role, selecting "properties, and then Adding an endpoint under the Endpoints tab. It doesn't allow me to set the same public port for two different roles. Perhaps this isn't the correct way to do things?

Comment: Did you have two web roles on your solution, one for web service and one for web site. So you set your web service role to 80 and your web site role to 8081, is that correct?

Comment: Yes That is correct. Was that not the right way to do things?

Comment: I think it should be possible to have more than one web role in one cloud project with different port. But I didn't tried. I need more time to investigate if I have the time. Maybe someone can help here with their experience. Anyway, I will get back to you if I found something.

Answer (score 0):

Check the port numbers. Each of the endpoints (the wcf endpoint and the web endpoint) need to be on different port numbers. You'll need to access them as such when published to Azure.

The random-name issue is from publishing to Staging vs Production, as @Shaun pointed out.

Comment: That was it, i had to enter the port number. Is there a way to get to the url without entering the port number?